# Jersey API with Spring SessionFactory NullpointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jersey

[Images of All Jars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwXeu.jpg)

[This is the error image from the console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8UVL.jpg)

I am trying to use the Jersey API along with Spring and Hibernate. However, defining session factory says NullPointerException. Can anybody help me to solve this? Added Full configuration with spring, hibernate and Jersey. Images of error and jar on top.

```
            ---------------------Dao Class:

            package com.org.restservice.bo.user;

            import java.util.List;

            import com.org.restservice.common.Dao;

            public interface AuthenticationDao extends Dao{

                /*
                 * User Information List
                 */
                public List userInfo(AuthenticationVo authenticationVo) throws Exception;


            }


            ---------------------DaoHibernate Class:

            package com.org.restservice.bo.user;

            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.Iterator;
            import java.util.List;

            import javax.sql.DataSource;

            import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
            import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
            import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
            import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
            import org.hibernate.SQLQuery;
            import org.hibernate.Session;
            import org.hibernate.type.StringType;
            import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateCallback;

            import com.org.restservice.common.BaseDaoHibernate;
            import com.org.restservice.common.Constant;


            public class AuthenticationDaoHibernate extends BaseDaoHibernate implements AuthenticationDao{

                private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(AuthenticationDaoHibernate.class);
                private DataSource dataSource;

                public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
                            this.dataSource = dataSource;
                }

                /*
                * User Information List
                 */
                public List userInfo(AuthenticationVo authenticationVo) throws Exception{

                    System.out.println("Called Me>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");

                     List<AuthenticationVo> findlist = new ArrayList<AuthenticationVo>();

                     final String sqlQuery = "SELECT USER_ID, ROLE_ID from STTM_USER_MASTER";                

                     System.out.println("sqlQuery: "+sqlQuery);

                           List results = (List) getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback() {
                               public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException {
                                   SQLQuery sq = session.createSQLQuery(sqlQuery);
                                   sq.addScalar("USER_ID", StringType.INSTANCE);
                                   sq.addScalar("ROLE_ID", StringType.INSTANCE);                       
                                   return sq.list();

                                 }
                           });


                          try {
                                if (results.size() > 0) {
                                    Iterator itr = results.iterator();
                                    while (itr.hasNext()) {
                                        authenticationVo = new AuthenticationVo();
                                        Object[] row = (Object[]) itr.next();   
                                        authenticationVo.setUser_id((String) row[0]);
                                        authenticationVo.setRole_id((String) row[1]);                           

                                        findlist.add(authenticationVo);

                                    }

                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println("FunctonVos error:" + e.getMessage());
                            }

                            System.out.println("Size of User List is: "
                                    + findlist.size());


                            System.out.println("Procedure call ended.");

                           return findlist;

                }



            }

            ---------------------Facade Class:

            package com.org.restservice.bo.user;

            import java.util.List;

            import com.org.restservice.common.Facade;



            public interface AuthenticationFacade extends Facade{

            public void setAuthenticationDao(AuthenticationDao authenticationDao);

            /*
             * User Information List
             */
            public List userInfo(AuthenticationVo authenticationVo) throws Exception;


            }


            ---------------------FacadeImpl Class:

            package com.org.restservice.bo.user;

            import java.util.List;

            import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
            import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

            import com.org.restservice.common.BaseFacade;


            public class AuthenticationFacadeImpl extends BaseFacade implements AuthenticationFacade{

                private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(AuthenticationFacadeImpl.class);

                private AuthenticationDao authenticationDao;

                public void setAuthenticationDao(AuthenticationDao authenticationDao) {
                    this.authenticationDao = authenticationDao;
                }

                /*
                 * User Information List
                 */
                public List userInfo(AuthenticationVo authenticationVo) throws Exception{

                    return authenticationDao.userInfo(authenticationVo);
                }


            }


            ---------------------Business Object Class:

            package com.org.restservice.bo.user;


            import com.org.restservice.common.BaseObject;


            public class AuthenticationVo  extends BaseObject{


                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                private String user_id; 
                private String role_id;

                public AuthenticationVo(String user_id, String role_id) {
                    super();
                    this.user_id = user_id;
                    this.role_id = role_id;
                }

                public AuthenticationVo() {
                    super();
                }

                public String getUser_id() {
                    return user_id;
                }

                public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
                    this.user_id = user_id;
                }

                public String getRole_id() {
                    return role_id;
                }

                public void setRole_id(String role_id) {
                    this.role_id = role_id;
                }

                @Override
                public int hashCode() {
                    final int prime = 31;
                    int result = 1;
                    result = prime * result + ((role_id == null) ? 0 : role_id.hashCode());
                    result = prime * result + ((user_id == null) ? 0 : user_id.hashCode());
                    return result;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                    if (this == obj)
                        return true;
                    if (obj == null)
                        return false;
                    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                        return false;
                    AuthenticationVo other = (AuthenticationVo) obj;
                    if (role_id == null) {
                        if (other.role_id != null)
                            return false;
                    } else if (!role_id.equals(other.role_id))
                        return false;
                    if (user_id == null) {
                        if (other.user_id != null)
                            return false;
                    } else if (!user_id.equals(other.user_id))
                        return false;
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public String toString() {
                    return "AuthenticationVo [user_id=" + user_id + ", role_id=" + role_id + "]";
                } 

            }

            ---------------------Action Class Declaration:

            package com.org.restservice.portal.user;

            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.List;
            import javax.ws.rs.GET;
            import javax.ws.rs.Path;
            import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
            import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
            import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
            import com.org.restservice.bo.user.AuthenticationFacade;
            import com.org.restservice.bo.user.AuthenticationVo;

            @Path("userService")
            public class UserAction{

                private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(UserAction.class);    
                AuthenticationVo authenticationVo = new AuthenticationVo();
                private AuthenticationFacade authenticationFacade = null;
                private List<AuthenticationVo> listofUsers = new ArrayList<AuthenticationVo>();



                public AuthenticationVo getAuthenticationVo() {
                    return authenticationVo;
                }

                public void setAuthenticationVo(AuthenticationVo authenticationVo) {
                    this.authenticationVo = authenticationVo;
                }

                public AuthenticationFacade getAuthenticationFacade() {
                    return authenticationFacade;
                }

                public void setAuthenticationFacade(AuthenticationFacade authenticationFacade) {
                    this.authenticationFacade = authenticationFacade;
                }

                public List<AuthenticationVo> getListofUsers() {
                    return listofUsers;
                }

                public void setListofUsers(List<AuthenticationVo> listofUsers) {
                    this.listofUsers = listofUsers;
                }


                @GET
                @Produces( "application/json" )
                public List<AuthenticationVo> customAction(){

                    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                        log.debug("Entering into loadusers Method of AuthenticationAction: " +authenticationFacade);
                    }
                    try {
                        listofUsers = authenticationFacade.userInfo(authenticationVo);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }   
                    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" +listofUsers.size());

                    /*authenticationVo.setUser_id("1234");
                    authenticationVo.setRole_id("134352");
                    listofUsers.add(authenticationVo);*/

                    return listofUsers;
                }


            }


            ---------------------Spring Beans Declaration:

            <!-- <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"> -->

            <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
                xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

                <!-- Database connection using jndi properties-->
                <import resource="config/applicationContext-jndi.xml"/> 

                <import resource="config/applicationContext.xml"/>

                <!-- List and Setup -->
                <import resource="config/applicationContext-auth.xml"/>


            </beans>


            ---------------------Application Context Declaration:

            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
                    "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

            <beans>


                <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
                    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
                    <property name="mappingResources">
                        <list>


                        </list>
                    </property>
                    <property name="hibernateProperties">
                        <props>
                            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                            <prop key="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</prop>
                        </props>
                    </property>
                </bean>

                <!-- Transaction manager for a single Hibernate SessionFactory (alternative to JTA) -->

                 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
                    <property name="sessionFactory">
                        <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
                    </property>
                </bean>

                <!-- Transaction template for Facade -->
                <bean id="txProxyTemplate" abstract="true"
                      class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
                    <property name="transactionManager">
                        <ref bean="transactionManager"/>
                    </property>
                    <property name="transactionAttributes">
                        <props>
                            <prop key="save*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                            <prop key="remove*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                            <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
                        </props>
                    </property>
                </bean>


                <!-- DAO bean -->

                <!-- Generic DAO - can be used when doing standard CRUD -->
                <bean id="dao" class="com.org.restservice.common.BaseDaoHibernate">
                    <property name="sessionFactory">
                        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
                    </property>
                    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                </bean>

                <!-- Generic Facade that can be used to do basic CRUD operations on any 
                    objects -->
                <bean id="facade" parent="txProxyTemplate">
                    <property name="target">
                        <bean class="com.org.restservice.common.BaseFacade">
                            <property name="Dao" ref="dao" />
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>


            </beans>


            --------------------- Context Declaration:

            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
                    "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

            <beans>


                <!-- Transaction declarations for business services. -->

                <bean id="authenticationFacade" parent="txProxyTemplate">
                    <property name="target">
                        <bean
                            class="com.org.restservice.bo.user.AuthenticationFacadeImpl">
                            <property name="authenticationDao">
                                <ref bean="authenticationDao" />
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>

                <!-- authenticationDao: Hibernate implementation -->
                <bean id="authenticationDao"
                    class="com.org.restservice.bo.user.AuthenticationDaoHibernate">
                    <property name="sessionFactory">
                        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
                    </property>

                    <property name="dataSource">
                        <ref bean="dataSource" />
                    </property>

                </bean>


            </beans>


            ---------------------Jndi Declaration:

            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
                    "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

                <!-- author: Sarkar Zahir Ahamed <ahamed.sarkar@dbbl.com.bd> -->

            <beans>

                <!-- ========================= PERSISTENCE DEFINITIONS ========================= -->
                <!-- JNDI DataSource for J2EE environments -->
                <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
                    <property name="jndiName">
                        <value>java:/comp/env/jndi/orcl</value>                       
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </beans>



            ---------------------Web XML Declaration:

            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
              <display-name>RestWebService</display-name>

             <!-- Spring Listener -->
                <listener>
                    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
                </listener>

                <!-- Jersey Servlet -->
                <servlet>
                    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
                    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
                    <!-- Register resources and providers -->
                    <init-param>
                        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
                        <param-value>com.org.restservice</param-value>
                    </init-param>
                    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
                </servlet>

                <servlet-mapping>
                    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
                    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
                </servlet-mapping>

                <!-- loading Spring Context for registering beans with ApplicationContext -->
                <context-param>
                    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                    <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/SpringBeans.xml</param-value>
                </context-param>

                <!-- welcome file -->
                <welcome-file-list>
                    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
                </welcome-file-list>

            </web-app>
```

Comment: Well finally I have solve the problem. What happened actually authentificationFacade i have declared as a bean in XML file is not injecting during run time for some reason. What I have done just add the following code to manually inject the bean in the method called getLists().                                                                  ApplicationContext ctx = ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
  authenticationFacade = (AuthenticationFacade) getBean("authenticationFacade");

Comment: @SZAhamed if you are using Spring why don't you Autowire the bean rather that manually loading it